# asp .net core - custom validation errors not displayed on view

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, html-helper

This is my data model, and it includes one custom validation:

```
public class MyData : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string text { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (text.Length < number)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "Text too short, must be at least: " + number.ToString(),
                new[] { "number" });
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part of my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="number" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="number" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="number" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The custom validation error text is never displayed where asp-validation-for shoud put it (when field data is absent, the standard message The number field is required." is displayed correctly).

However if I add this code segment in the view:

```
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("number")
</div>
```

... it will display the custom error message.

What is the problem with asp-validation-for helper?

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out in your code you are using

```
<span asp-validation-for="number" class="text-danger" />
```

You need to add the closing tag. Use it like

```
<span asp-validation-for="number" class="text-danger" ></span>
```

and it'll show the error messages right under the field.

Comment: Doh! Thank you! Self-closed tag prevented the value from rendering. Naturally I checked everything else it could be first. Will not forget next time, I hope.